# IFrame Background Image not show in IE6 and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, background-image

i need help .
its work ok in firefox or Opera.
the problem is in ie.
i try to put it in style file , or inline style but not effect.

Comment: Add some code to this question, it's hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting allowTransparency="true" on the iframe and setting the background color of the document body of the child frame to transparent?

See the MSDN documentation on allowTransparency:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533072(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Even though it is not working

<iframe scrolling="auto" name="main" style="background-color: green;allowTransparency=true;width:100%;height:90%;background-image:url(ProductVehicleCombo_Problem.JPG)"> </iframe>

Comment: priyanka: take another look at your syntax there.  allowTransparency is an attribute of the iframe tag, not a style property.

Answer (score 1):

in researching this issue, some posts used ALLOWTRANSPARENCY in all caps.  ie7 (in ie9 developer tools) didn't respond to it until I camelcased it to "allowTransparency".

For what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. it should work(tested in IE/Firefox/Google Crome)

```
<div><img src="a.JPG"></div>

<div>
<iframe style="display:none" width="325" height="276" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```